# Unable to find out an error in JSON payload as per JWT exception on GitLab C

Tags: java, json, jwt

I have to create some test data before running some BDD test on to GitLab CI environment.

**API endpoint:**

```
 POST http://localhost:8001/some.server.address/names/create
```

**JSON Payload:**

```
{"name":"ReportConfig_ci_FhYVlJqCsjY7_1l4OHkl3hvcC","reportConfig":"1","country":"India","industry":"Oil","rating":"AAA","comparableSet":"1","cds":"1","clientId":"123"}
```

**It is giving the following exception:**

> {   "timestamp" : "2019-01-17T06:32:09.814+0000",   "status" : 403,
>   "error" : "Forbidden",   "message" : "Exception when trying to
>   authenticate token io.jsonwebtoken.MalformedJwtException: Unable to
>   read JSON value: \u0005�z��&\u0016�r#�$�3S\u0013\"",   "path" :
>   "/some.server.address/names/create" }

1. How can I resolve this exception?
2. Is something incorrect I am passing in the payload?
3. Is there any link or website on which I can check for these specific
   values so that I can modify the JSON?

**Note:** Suggestion about any of above would be a great help.

Comment: The payload seems to be fine but the JWT token used for authentication is somehow broken.

Comment: the authentication token that I am using is [ eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6InZhaWJoYXYuc2hhcm1hIn0.R9f8wJwiie7kuUqc5lZHzuFq65YRNBsbnxaFMfcfEVR4lFZqoQPkLWdQmdVH9aKqSNY-9tNJWlQjljkNOFEDzw ] It is working fine for the other API request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is resolved by adding a request header into the builder and by changing the port number in API configuration.

> .accept(MediaType.WILDCARD)

```
WebTarget endpoint = client.target(url);
    Invocation.Builder builder = endpoint.
            request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
            .accept(MediaType.WILDCARD)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .header("Authorization", token.getToken());
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Check for URL errors and make sure you're specifying an actual web page file name and extension, not just a directory. Most websites are configured to disallow directory browsing, so a 403 Forbidden message when trying to display a folder instead of a specific page, is normal and expected.

2)Clear your browser's cache. Issues with a cached version of the page you're viewing could be causing 403 Forbidden issues.

3)Log in to the website, assuming it's possible and appropriate to do so. A 403 Forbidden message could mean that you need additional access before you can view the page.

Typically, a website produces a 401 Unauthorized error when special permission is required, but sometimes a 403 Forbidden is used instead.

4)Contact the website directly. It's possible that the 403 Forbidden error is a mistake, everyone else is seeing it, too, and the website isn't yet aware of the problem.

See our Website Contact Information list for contact information for lots of popular websites. Most sites have support-based accounts on social networking sites, making it really easy to get a hold of them. Some even have support email addresses and telephone numbers.

5)Clear your browser's cookies, especially if you typically log in to this website and logging in again

Comment: On UI these are working fine but I am running these tests on to CI environment i.e. headless or ghost mode. This error I am getting on to GitLab runner console on GitLab CI environment.